# Display an alternative background image in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, background, styles

style={{
backgroundImage:
"url(" +
"http://production-partner-cdn.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/general-files/jash%20jpeg.jpg" +
")"
}}

i want to display an alternative image if this image link is not valid

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: if the actual url for bg image doesnt contain any image display an alt  image

Answer (score 0):

You can provide comma separated urls

```js
style={{ 
        backgroundImage:`url(${some_url}), url(${some_fallback_url})`
    }}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Comment: hi thanks i tried it but when the first url is valid second url is getting displayed .. style={{
            backgroundImage:
              "url(" +
              headerImage +
              ")" , backgroundImage:
              "url(" +
              "http://production-partner-cdn.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/general-files/jash%20jpeg.jpg" +
              ")" 
          }}